# How to secure MySQL Connection and Informations On Desktop App

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, electron

i'm really new to these things. Normally in making website it's easy to secure it becasue everything is actually local. Just PHP or someting like that process data and shows up in a static page. But when we got desktop app i don't know how to do it. How can i make app <-> server relation? Like Instagram or Facebook or something like that. At the first i think JSON might work for that, but it think it's not secure for all information.I hope i explained good.

Comment: 1. All comms done over https or some encrypted connection

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Little bit late but if someone comes here, here's the answer you're looking for; HTTP. Yeah It's that simple. Learn how HTTP works. For making security tight, look for cross origin resource sharing (CORS), two-way encryption, server-side validation and so on. Have a good day!